# Why does gmail shows idle when I am signed out thus consuming data from my android core prime?

Tags: settings

Going to Accounts and removing sync off does not help.  removing the gmail app does not help as well. I am not logged on to my gmail account however when a friend checks their mail, finds me being idle even though i am not signed in. why does this happen as it is consuming data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Greenify** and hibernate it. [You must be rooted.]

Comment: You should provide a link to the app, this would make the answer more useful.

Comment: Goto Google Play Store and type 'Greenify' in the search bar... You will get it.